# Angular Display values in a list based on an array populated by Entity Framework query

Tags: html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to populate a list (ul li) with data from an array that is populated via Entity Framework code.

The following works to populate a option dropdown:

```
<select class="form-control" name="Search" 
    data-ng-model="formData.ProviderFullName2" id="ProviderSearch"
    data-ng-options="c.FULL_NAME as c.FULL_NAME for c in myArray">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Full Name</option>
</select>
```

How can I achieve the same using a UL LI? I've tried the following but failed:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="c.FULL_NAME as c.FULL_NAME for c in myArray">
    {{c.FULL_NAME}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What's in your `myArray` variable?

Comment: Try with ng-repeat="c in myArray"

Answer (score 1):

Whoops; it was easy:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="fullname in myArray">
    {{fullname.FULL_NAME}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm sure you can come up with some better explanatory naming :-)

Comment: You are right!! I did it on whim and didn't think too much about 'name' - too many names!!!